# Why is `0x83 0x00` well-formed encoding of 3 as a u8 in Wasm?

Tags: webassembly

[image]

(source: http://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/binary/values.html#integers)

According to my understanding of specification, value 3 should be encoded to `0x03` for `u8`. (It satisfies the condition of "if n < 2<sup>7</sup> ∧ n < 2<sup>N</sup>")

By the way, the next paragraph says like this:

The side conditions N>7 in the productions for non-terminal bytes of the u and s encodings restrict the encoding’s length. However, “trailing zeros” are still allowed within these bounds. For example, 0x03 and 0x83 0x00 are both well-formed encodings for the value 3 as a u8.

I get 0x83 0x00 by the second equation, but it's for the case of "if n ≥ 2<sup>7</sup> ∧ N < 7". For value 3, it doesn't satisfy the condition of "n ≥ 2<sup>7</sup>" How can `0x83 0x00` be a well-formed encodings in this case?

Comment: Could you please provide a link to your source, not just the screenshot?

Comment: I added the original link to screenshot within post.

Comment: Maybe fill in a bug for the specification for me it seems the "and" should replaced by "or" because it is opposing the ceil(N/7). So why 0x83 0x00 is legal because you can code it more lazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be interpreting the specification in the wrong direction. It specifies *decoding*, not *encoding*. So in the example, n is not the value 3, but the byte value `0x83`. 3 should equal the right-hand side formula "2^7 * m + (n - 2^7)". This is the case because m (the value of the second byte) will be 0.